# Issue with Square API on WooCommerce/Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, credit-card, square

I have a Word Press/Woo Commerce site that customers have the ability to pay for items with a credit card using the Square Plug In. (valleyfirewoodak.com)

The credit card feature was implemented around August 2017 and worked fine.  Mid February 2018, I received the first notice of a "failed" order.

At first I didn't think too much of it, I thought it was just a declined card, or the customer had made a typo.  I am able to take payment when I make the delivery, so it wasn't a big deal.
A few weeks went by and I got a few more failed orders, which is when I realized something wasn't working.

The order info had this in the error log:
Unknown Error Order status changed from Pending payment to Failed.

Not much help.

I found some plug in and templates files out of date.  After those were all updated, I tested the site by placing an order.  It failed, but I was able to get an error now:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[category] => AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
[code] => UNAUTHORIZED
[detail] => This request could not be authorized.
)

)
Order status changed from Pending payment to Failed.
```

I don't understand exactly what this is saying.  Can anyone help?  I'm left to figure it out on my own, the "website designer" I was using threw in the towel a few days ago.  After going through several I'm trying to just learn on my own instead of spending more money with false hopes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like your website may not be able to connect to the Square API. In the admin panel, try disconnecting and reconnecting to your Square account. [Docs here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-square/).

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue you simply have to ensure that the Square profile and the website business address are the same. It's a new Square requirement that is catching people by surprise due to their lack of letting people know about that.